# add_action() not working for admin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, actions

Making my own custom plugin and using add_action several times without a problem with one exception. Currently function below are located in functions.php in the appropriate themes folder.

```
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
   error_log('enqueue_custom_scripts function is executing'); // In enqueue_custom_scripts
   
   wp_enqueue_script('custom-ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-ajax-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

   wp_localize_script('custom-ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array(
       'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
       'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('my-custom-ajax-nonce'),
   ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');
```

I have tried several version of this, in several files including plugin main file. Note: Not even the error_log trigger. The odd thing is that it works if user not logged in. Probably some stupid mistake I made so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/), the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook (emphasis mine):

> ...is the proper hook to use when enqueuing scripts and styles that are
> meant to appear **on the front end**.

If you want to enqueue scripts in the admin, you need to use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/).